# Express js does not serve static files

Tags: node.js, express

I have mounted path like this

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var admin = express();

admin.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/')));

// mount admin path
app.use('/admin', admin);
```

Then I defined some route e.g

```
admin.get('/jobs', function(req, res){ 
   res.render('jobs/index');
});

admin.get('/jobs/create', function(req, res){ 
   res.render('jobs/create');
});
```

In the first route static files such as `js,css,images` loaded w/o problems.
But in second one it does not load files.

Files loaded in views like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/main.css">
```

NOTE :  styles directory is under public folder in my working directory.

So what is the problem ? What I did wrong ?

Comment: Use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/css/main.css">`. You need to add `/` at the starting for static assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static middleware is added to the `admin` express instance, which is mounted in the main `app` at the `/admin` route. This means it will never get called for routes other than those matching `/admin`. Move your middleware to the main app instance instead,

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: That is the problem . I want to serve different static files for `admin` and for `front`. That's why I added different static folders . What is really interesting it works with `/admin/jobs` but does not for `/admin/jobs/create`.

Comment: The reason it works for `/admin/jobs`, but not `/admin/jobs/create` is because you are using a relative path to your stylesheet. So for `/admin/jobs` it resolves to `/admin/styles/css/main.css` (which works), while for `/admin/jobs/create` it resolves to `/admin/jobs/styles/css/main.css` (which doesn't). You can instead use the absolute path `/admin/styles/css/main.css`, i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/styles/css/main.css">`, which should work.

Comment: Alternatively, if you always want to serve your stylesheet from the public url `/styles/css/main.css`, then simply create a separate route for it, along the lines of `app.get('/styles/css/main.css', (req, res) => res.sendFile(...))`. You can include logic in this route handler to determine what stylesheet to serve the user.

Answer (score 0):

First: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Then `href="/styles/css/main.css"`?

Hope it helps.

Comment: No . I modified code . added slash after `public` please have a look . Still does not work .

Comment: Well, **public** directory is accesbile for static files at **/** path. So the slash you added at the end does nothing.

You have to access to absolute path **/public** from the views.

Comment: Edited answer does not work even for the first route .